# Boot memory /dev/sda1/boot full

Tags: boot

My computer keeps asking me to update but there is no space, boot memory at 100%.  Have tried `apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo rm .xsessions-errors`.

None of which work. Any suggestions greatfully received.  NB, I am NOT a computer whiz so baby steps PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command removes the unnecessary packages

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This is same as a clean command

you can also use Ubuntu tweak program and clean using janitor option

Comment: Those commands apply to `apt` cache located in `/var/apt/cache`. Nothing to do with `/boot`

Answer (score 0):

boot partition contains boot loader files, kernels, modules, init ram disks and some additional components. Probably you have few versions of kernels + adds and it consumes you space within /boot partition. For example:

root@server# ls -1 /boot
abi-3.11.0-15-generic
abi-3.11.0-17-generic
abi-3.11.0-20-generic
abi-3.11.0-23-generic
abi-3.11.0-24-generic
abi-3.8.0-29-generic
abi-3.8.0-35-generic
abi-3.8.0-36-generic
abi-3.8.0-39-generic
abi-3.8.0-42-generic
config-3.11.0-15-generic
config-3.11.0-17-generic
config-3.11.0-20-generic
config-3.11.0-23-generic
config-3.11.0-24-generic
config-3.8.0-29-generic
config-3.8.0-35-generic
config-3.8.0-36-generic
config-3.8.0-39-generic
config-3.8.0-42-generic
grub
initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-20-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-23-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-24-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-35-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-36-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-39-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-42-generic
System.map-3.11.0-15-generic
System.map-3.11.0-17-generic
System.map-3.11.0-20-generic
System.map-3.11.0-23-generic
System.map-3.11.0-24-generic
System.map-3.8.0-29-generic
System.map-3.8.0-35-generic
System.map-3.8.0-36-generic
System.map-3.8.0-39-generic
System.map-3.8.0-42-generic
vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic
vmlinuz-3.11.0-23-generic
vmlinuz-3.11.0-24-generic
vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
vmlinuz-3.8.0-36-generic
vmlinuz-3.8.0-39-generic
vmlinuz-3.8.0-42-generic

Check which version of the kernel(s) you are really using now and remove unnecessary ones.

BE CAREFUL! ;-)